# How do I remove any and all characters before the first period in a file name?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, files, rename

I have 1366 files whose file names start with up to four numbers. For example:

```
128.unique filename.flac
6.unique filename.flac
1288.unique filename.flac
```

I want to remove all numbers and the period, so that way, all of the files will exist like so:

```
unique filename.flac
unique filename.flac
unique filename.flac
```

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. How might I achieve this?

Comment: You can't have 3 different files in a directory all with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using shell

Let's start with these files:

```
$ ls
'unique filename 1.flac'  'unique filename 2.flac'  'unique filename
```

Let's run this command:

```
$ for f in [0-9]*flac; do mv "$f" "${f#*.}"; done
```

After the above executes, the files are:

```
$ ls
'unique filename 1.flac'  'unique filename 2.flac'  'unique filename 3.flac'
```

`for f in [0-9]*flac; do` starts a `for` loop over each file name that starts with a number and ends with `flac`.  `mv "$f" "${f#*.}"` removes the beginning of the filename up to and including the first period. `done` signals the end of the `for` loop.

#### Perl's `rename` command

There are two **incompatible** utilities named `rename`.  This method applies to the `rename` command (sometimes called `prename`) that comes with Perl.

If you have the other `rename` installed, this method won't work.

Let's again start with these files and then run the `prename` command:

```
$ ls
'1288.unique filename 3.flac'  '128.unique filename 1.flac'  '6.unique filename 2.flac'
$ prename 's/^\d+\.//' [0-9]*flac
$ ls
'unique filename 1.flac'  'unique filename 2.flac'  'unique filename 3.flac'
```

Perl's rename uses regular expressions.  `\d+\.` matches one or more digits followed by a period.  `^` requires that those digits appear at the beginning of the file name.  `s/^\d+\.//` causes those digits and the period to be replaced with nothing.